# I got the proble in using industify theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using industify theme wordpress im facing the problem accordion,when i click on it its oppen and close multiple times insted of open once whats the problem please guide me as soons as possile

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take your time and go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [check how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.